# Трехтабличный запрос к базе данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть запрос к базе, к одной таблице с помощью pdo

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  lastname,
  login,
  birthday,
  main_photo
FROM
  users
WHERE
  id = :id
```

Каким образом модифицировать запрос чтоб выборка была из трех разных таблиц? Я делаю следующим образом:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  lastname,
  login,
  birthday,
  main_photo
FROM
  users,
  regals,
  user_info
WHERE
   id = :id
```

Спасибо

Comment: Вы условия для склейки таблиц напишите, без условий склейки они все перемножаться и решите зачем оно вообще нужно. может вам не склейка а union нужен. так что лучше напишите в впоросе структуру таблиц, какие примерно в них записи и что на выходе должен дать запрос

Answer (score 1):

Эмм, так он и так из трёх таблиц. Или Вы про join говорите?

```
SELECT *
  FROM users u
       JOIN regals r ON r.id = u.id
       JOIN user_info ui ON ui.id = u.id
 WHERE u.id = :id
```

Comment: На самом деле я без понятия что такое join и что такое union. И из таблицы users кроме ид еще другие поля выбираются, а из двух других таблиц только поля с ид

Comment: @alexandr.patrachi то что выбирается написано после слова select, в данном случае это `*` - т.е. все поля из всех таблиц. а в условиях join говорится по каким условиям таблицы соединяются. т.е. какие записи из regals например выбрать к конкретной записи из users. слова join можно было бы заменить на запятые (как у вас изначально) и написать условия соединения в where. И ваш запрос не сложный, просто написать его невозможно не понимая что именно вы хотите получить. Самому научится писать запросы такого уровня вполне можно за 1 день.

Comment: Что хочу получить я понимаю. Есть три таблицы users, regals, user_info, я хочу одним запросом выбрать из таблицы users поля id, name, lastname, login, birthday, main_photo а из таблиц regals и user_info по полю id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  u.id, 
  u.name,
  u.lastname,
  u.login,
  u.birhday,
  u.main_photo,
  r.id,
  ui.id
FROM
  users AS u
INNER JOIN
  regals AS r 
ON
  r.id = u.id
INNER JOIN
  user_info AS ui
ON
  ui.id = u.id
WHERE
  u.id = id пользователя.
```

Однако это при условии что у тебя будут связи между таблицами. Или просто используй к каждой таблице свой `SELECT`, а между ними ставь `UNION` для объединения выборок в результате.